# ReactJs - onClick not firing

Tags: reactjs

Probably a super noobie question, but does anyone know why my onClick is not firing? I have tried changing the z-index in my CSS in case the button was too far back, but this did not change anything.

Here is my button module:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './button.module.css';

const button = (props)=>{

    return(
        <button onClick={()=>{console.log("hello");props.select()}} className={classes.button}>
            <div className={classes.text_center}>
            <div className={classes.button_text}>{props.text}</div></div>
        </button>
    );
}

export default button;
```

Later on I call the module:

```
this.state.skills?null:<Button select={()=>{console.log("hi");this.setState({skills:true})}} text={"Skills"}></Button>}.
```

The button actually displays fine, and the text is passed as a prop, but unfortunately I can't get the onClick to fire. Neither of the two console.log statements fire.

All help is appreciated.

///

As requested in the comments button.module.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    src: url('../../../Fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf') format('truetype') /* IE6-IE8 */
  }

.button_choice{
    width:10vw;
    height:10vh;
    top:25%;
    border: 2px solid #4ca3dd;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:5vw;
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;

}

.button_choice:hover{
    background-color: red;
}



.text_center{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display: table;
}

.text_center:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}

.button_text{
   font-family:"Raleway";
   position:relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

/////

Slight break through :/, when considering the 3 classes below, .background_init is a div spreading over the whole page. On the press of a button, this div slides to half of the size on the left by changing to the class .background_left. The buttons are contained within background_right. If I change height in .background_left to 200px, the buttons work (including hover), but obviously this completely messes up my styling. Any suggestions?

```
.background_init{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-color: #4ca3dd;


}

.background_left{
    width:50vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: #4ca3dd;
    transition: width 2s;
}

.background_right{
        overflow: auto;
        width:50vw;
        height:100vh;
        transition: width 2s;


 }
```

Comment: provide jsfiddle so that can debug

Comment: Your code is working fine. Can you provide codepen for the issue?

Comment: To be honest, I' not really sure how to do that. I ahve just noticed that :hover is not triggering on the buttons either :/

Comment: Can you post your `button.module.css`?

Comment: I just added it to the question - thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the `button` class? Also you are hovering over `button_choice` but not used anywhere in your component.

Comment: I think `className={classes.button}` should be `className={classes.button_choice}`

Comment: Sorry, it was earlier. I changed the className to className={classes.button_choice also} in order to test button_choice:hover

Comment: I have found the CSS affecting the issue, but I am unsure of how to fix it/why this issue is being caused.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this works, but instead of using 100vh and 100vw, I used display:absolute and width:50%/ 100% and height:100%. If anyone can explain why this works I would be extremely grateful.